# How do I create a desaturated version of a Display P3 color?

Tags: rgb, uicolor, color-space, hsb

I have a [color](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor) `UIColor(displayP3Red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0.8, alpha: 1)`. I want to create a desaturated version of this — with the same hue and brightness, but less saturation, like half the saturation of the original. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
extension UIColor {    
  // Calling this with 0.5 as argument returns a color whose saturation is 50% of that of the receiver.
  func desaturatedBy(fraction: CGFloat) -> UIColor {
    var hue: CGFloat = 0
    var saturation: CGFloat = 0
    var brightness: CGFloat = 0
    var alpha: CGFloat = 0
    let success = getHue(&hue, saturation: &saturation, brightness: &brightness, alpha: &alpha)
    assert(success)

    saturation *= fraction

    return UIColor(hue: hue, saturation: saturation, brightness: brightness, alpha: alpha)
  }
}
```

This works because the getter returns HSB in the extended sRGB color space, and UIColor's initialiser takes HSB in the extended sRGB color space, too. So we don't need to do any color space conversion.

Answer (score 0):

It should be straightforward given you can compute the Normalised Primary Matrix (NPM) of DCI-P3: the middle row of the NPM represents the Luminance factors. I will illustrate this using [Colour](https://github.com/colour-science/colour), it assumes that you are using linear values:

```python
import numpy as np
import colour

# Computing the sRGB Luminance Equation, you should be familiar with the 
# resulting Luminance factors.
print(colour.RGB_luminance_equation(
    colour.sRGB_COLOURSPACE.primaries, 
    colour.sRGB_COLOURSPACE.whitepoint))
# Y = 0.212639005872(R) + 0.715168678768(G) + 0.0721923153607(B)

# Computing the DCI-P3 Luminance Equation.
print(colour.RGB_luminance_equation(
    colour.DCI_P3_COLOURSPACE.primaries, 
    colour.DCI_P3_COLOURSPACE.whitepoint))
# Y = 0.209491677913(R) + 0.721595254161(G) + 0.0689130679262(B)

# Computing Luminance of given RGB colour, this is assuming it is representing linear values.
DCI_P3_LUMINANCE_FACTORS = np.array([0.209491677913, 0.721595254161, 0.0689130679262])
RGB = np.array([1.0, 0.0, 0.8])
Y = np.dot(RGB, DCI_P3_LUMINANCE_FACTORS)
print(Y)
# 0.264622132254
```

With **Y** representing the Luminance of your given colour, if you wanted to desaturate at 50% you could do something like that:

> lerp(RGB, [Y, Y, Y], 0.5)

Comment: Is there a way to do this in iOS? Thanks.

Comment: Very likely, what you really just need is being able to do a dot product and a linear interpolation.

Comment: BTW, Python signals an error saying colour is not found in import colour. What MacPorts module must I install? I'm using Python 3.6. I already installed numpy, because that was giving an error too. Thanks.

Comment: @VaddadiKartick: Colour is a regular Python package, you can get it either from pip or Anaconda (recommended): http://colour-science.org/installation-guide/

Comment: Would be nice for the downvoters to explain why they downvote.

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but maybe others did because the question was about iOS and the answer wasn't. Still, they should've appreciated your effort and given constructive feedback rather than a drive-by downvote.

Comment: I did not realise that UIColor was an iOS specific class, so to me the question was generic. It might be worth adding an iOS tag?

Comment: Done. Also added a link to the iOS documentation to clarify. Sorry that it wasn't clear the first time.